# Problems using options_for_select helper in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, helper, form-helpers

I'm trying to get a value from a select box in order to pass the value to the controller but after many attempts I end up with no solution.

Im have this:

```
<div class="field">
    <%= f.label :activityType %><br>
    <%= select_tag(:activityType, options_for_select([
                                                      ["Cycling", "Cycling"], 
                                                      ["Running", "Running"],                     
                                                      ["Swimming", "Swimming"], 
                                                      ["Gymn", "Gymn"]
                                                     ])) %>
</div>
```

What I'm I doing wrong? In the documentation they do the same ..

The problem is that my validation for presence = true say that the field is blank.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `f.label` so probably you also would like to use `f.select` instead `select_tag`. The main difference between them is that

```
select_tag(:activityType, options_for_select([[]]) )
```

gives exactly `activityType` param name, so it's accessible in controller via `params[:activityType]`, whereas:

```
f.select(:activityType, options_for_select([[]]) )
```

gives `params[:object_name][:activityType]`. So that, if you're creating an object via `params[:object_name]`, `activityType` is empty.

Note I'm using `:object_name` because I don't know your form object name.

Comment: It works! Thanks @blelump! One question, I have this code two "divs" below :

`<div class="field">
    <%= f.label :place_id %><br>

    <%= select_tag 'activity[place_id]', options_from_collection_for_select(Place.all, 'id', 'district') %>`

Can you explain me why this is different from what I wanted? 

This works very well.

Thanks

Comment: Assuming you have something like `@activity = Activity.last`. Then in view: `form_for(@activity) do |f|; f.select :place_id; end` or `form_for(@activity) do |f|; select_tag 'activity[state_id]'; end` or `form_tag ... do ; select_tag 'activity[state_id]'; end` are all equivalents. Having `f.select`, that `f` adds extra context (object name) to field name, so that `f.select :state_id` becomes `activity[state_id]`.

Comment: Thank you! Greetings from Portugal :D